# R data.table: How to use complex conditon with columns from two tables

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to join summarized data from table `b` to `a` according to conditions which nead several columns from both table `a` and `b`.

```
### data.table 
a <- data.table(id = 1:3)
a
###  +----+
###  | id |
###  +----+
###  |  1 |
###  |  2 |
###  |  3 |
###  +----+

b <- data.table(id = rep((1:3), each = 2), n = 1:6)
b
###  +---+---+
###  | d | n |
###  +---+---+
###  | 1 | 1 |
###  | 1 | 2 |
###  | 2 | 3 |
###  | 2 | 4 |
###  | 3 | 5 |
###  | 3 | 6 |
###  +---+---+
```

For example, sum up n from b for each id but only if n<5:

```
a[, .(n = sum(b$n[b$id == id & b$n < 5])), by = id]

###  +---+---+
###  | d | n |
###  +---+---+
###  | 1 | 3 |
###  | 2 | 7 |
###  | 3 | 0 |
###  +---+---+
```

This easy. the problem arise if there is some more complexity in `j`. For example,
remove from the computed n above the sum of id for each id in b.

```
a[, .(n = sum(b$n[b$id == id & b$n < 5]-b$id[b$id == id & b$n < 5])), by = id]

###  +----+---+
###  | id | n |
###  +----+---+
###  |  1 | 1 |   there are two in b id=1 => 2  3-2=1
###  |  2 | 3 |   there are two in b id=2 => 4  7-4=3
###  |  3 | 0 |   don't compute if in b: n<5
###  +----+---+
```

I know this is a very constructed example. The problem here is that the condition

```
[b$id == id & b$n < 5]
```

may be very complex and may involves many more columns from both tables. It is very inconvinient to repeat always the same condition. I wonder if there is a way to omit this redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps join on an aggregated/filtered `b` instead?

```r
a[ b[n < 5, .(n = sum(n)), id], n := i.n, on = .(id)
        ][, n := fcoalesce(n, 0L)]
#       id     n
#    <int> <int>
# 1:     1     3
# 2:     2     7
# 3:     3     0

a[ b[n < 5, .(n = sum(n - id)), id], n := i.n, on = .(id)
        ][, n := fcoalesce(n, 0L)]
#       id     n
#    <int> <int>
# 1:     1     1
# 2:     2     3
# 3:     3     0
```

Comment: Or similarly join and use the filter criterion as a 0/1 value: `a[b, on=.(id)][, sum((n - id)*(n < 5)), by=id]`